# Data recovery after installing ubuntu (Chose “Erase disk and install Ubuntu”)

Tags: ubuntu, data-recovery, testdisk

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop and chose the option "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" from liveUSB without any backup. When I realized that this would format my whole HDD, I immediately unplugged the usb and turn off my laptop. However, it seems that my whole HDD had been formatted: I have 4 partitions before but there's only 1 partition formatted in ext4 now with the size equal the HDD's size.

Is there anyway I can get my data back? I believe that my data is still there on the disk. I've searched for a while and tried using Testdisk and parted but no luck: Testdisk cannot find any partition even after trying "Deeper Search"

Comment: In theory, they should still be there. Try this: http://www.disk-utilities.com/data-recovery/format-recovery.html. And by data you mean important files other than the previous OS files, right?

Comment: @WikiWitz: Yes, I mean my document and media files, not the OS files

Answer (score 1):

You can use **PhotoRec** in **sysresccd** Live Distro.

Read PhotoRec's manual fisrt. It's [here](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec_Step_By_Step).

Download **sysresccd** [here](http://www.sysresccd.org/Download).